# Using object methods without class instantiation in a MVC Web App Java EE

Tags: java, object, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, instantiation

I have a web application that allows me to add a Book object to a list displayed as a "datatable" using JSF, EJB, MVC, JPA.

The View code "listBooks.xhtml":

```
            <h:dataTable value="#{bookController.booklist}" var="elementBook" border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="isbn"> 
                <h:outputText value="ISBN"/> </f:facet>                    
                <h:outputText value="#{elementBook.isbn}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Title"/></f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{elementBook.title}"/>
                </h:column>  
                /* rest of the code */
            </h:dataTable>
```

The View Code "addNewBook.xhtml" :

```
<h:form> 
           <h4>
              ISBN:
              <h:inputText value="#{bookController.book.isbn}" size = "10" /> <br />
              Title:
             <h:inputText value="#{bookController.book.title}" size = "10" /> <br />  
              Price:
              <h:inputText value="#{bookController.book.price}" size = "10" /> <br />  
              Description:
              <h:inputTextarea value="#{bookController.book.description}" /> <br />
              Number of pages:
              <h:inputText value="#{bookController.book.bnOfPage}" size = "10" /> <br />  
              Illustrations:
              <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{bookController.book.illustrations}"/> <br />
              <h:commandButton value="Create a book" action="#{bookController.doCreateBook()}" />
             </h4>
             <hr/>
             <h2> Librairie en ligne</h2>

       </h:form>
```

Controller Layer :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BookController {

    @EJB
    private BookEJB bookEJB;
    private Book book;
    private List<Book> booklist;

    public BookController() {
        book = new Book();
        booklist=new ArrayList();
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public List<Book> getBooklist() {
        return booklist;
    }

    public void setBooklist(List<Book> booklist) {
        this.booklist = booklist;
    }

    public String doCreateBook() {
        bookEJB.create(book);
        booklist= bookEJB.findAll();
        return "listBooks.xhtml";

    }
}
```

Business Logic Layer :

```
@Stateless
public class BookEJB extends AbstractFacade<Book> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tpbookPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public BookEJB() {
        super(Book.class);
    }

    }
```

And an Abstract Facade :

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }
//......
```

And finally the Entity "Book" :

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Float price;
    private String description;
    private String isbn;
    private Integer bnOfPage;
    private Boolean illustrations;

    public Book(){
    }

    public Integer getBnOfPage() {
        return bnOfPage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Boolean getIllustrations() {
        return illustrations;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
```

The controller class "BookController", its job is to use the view to update the model, it declares a book variable `private Book book;` and the same for the EJB, `private BookEJB bookEJB;` and then using this `bookEJB.create(book);`

Shouldn't it be like `BookEJB bookEJB = new BookEJB();` and then doing the `bookEJB.create(book);` in the `doCreateBook()` method. Shouldn't we always use the `new` word to be able to use the object and access their methods ? because if we used just the name of the class instead we'll access just the static methods.

And then why using the `new` Keyword in the BookController constructor ? `Book book = new Book();` ?

Comment: Dependency injection will provide the BookEJB. That's what the `@EJB` annotation is for. I recommend tutorials and books at https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was wondering why we didn't use the "new" keyword and then using the bookEJB object ? and how the @EJB knew what EJB should inject without specifying its name ?

Comment: That's a big question, too big for StackOverflow. You should read [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnr.html) to start familiarizing yourself with the concepts. It will be fun because you have a lot to learn. Also, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL5bqoXFBWg) does an excellent job explaining dependency injection -- definitely watch that!

Comment: I edited my comment. Be sure to check out that video I linked to. It is short and answers your question, I think.